# Reference request on Fourier Analysis

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, book-recommendation

I would like to ask for some books on Fourier analysis treating it in more abstract way (possibly more on orthogonal systems, not just focusing on the trigonometric fourier series), not the applications.

Edit: I had measure theory course, but still didn't listen anything on functional analysis or differential equations. My knowledge of physics is basic-leveled.

Comment: I think you could precise the level a bit more. Debnath & Mikusinskii has a nice book (Hilbert spaces and its applications) that might fit. If you want something on a higher level, Grafakos books (Classical Fourier analysis and Modern Fourier analysis) could be what you look for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check it out. Just edited to give more information about the level.

Answer (score 1):

I think the book "Fourier Analysis and Its Applications" by Gerald B Folland has a quite abstract approach, despite its take on applications.

[http://www.amazon.com/Fourier-Analysis-Applications-Applied-Undergraduate/dp/0821847902](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847902)